# MySQL Error 1064 when trying to update with CASE

Tags: mysql

I wish to update my table each day and decrease the Days Training by one. If the gets 0 after decrementing, it should be set to NULL. If so, Sel. Training also must be set to NULL.
I figured out following Statement:

```
    UPDATE charakter 
    SET `Days Training` = CASE WHEN `Days Training` is > 0 
    THEN CASE WHEN `Days Training`-1 > 0 THEN `Days Training`-1 END,
    ELSE null 
    END,
    `Sel. Training` = CASE WHEN `Days Training` IS null THEN null END
```

However it returns #1064, meaning there's an error in the syntax. I can't find it, what am I doing wrong?

Edit:
I found my mistake, I have to include a WHERE Statement. My final and working Statement is as follows.

```
UPDATE charakter
  SET `Days Training` = 
    CASE 
      WHEN `Days Training`-1 = '0' then null 
      ELSE `Days Training`-1  
    END,
  `Sel. Training` = 
    CASE 
      WHEN `Days Training` = '0' then null 
      ELSE `Sel. Training` 
    END
WHERE 1
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the logic you want here is simply:

```
UPDATE charackter
SET `Days Training` = CASE WHEN `Days Training` > 1 THEN `Days Training` - 1 END;
```

By not providing an explicit `ELSE` condition, MySQL would just assign `NULL` for any case when the days of training be zero or less.  In this case, doing the decrement would result in a negative number, which you have stated you want replaced with `NULL`.

Comment: It gets NULL the second time, but I need to have the value be null if it would be zero otherwise.

Comment: Then check that the days training are at least 2 or more.  Then, a decrement to a days value of 1, which would result in zero, would be assigned to `NULL`.

Comment: my mistake was a missing WHERE clause. It works now but thank you for your help.